# Nivo Slider stopped working after Nextgen Gallery upgrade

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nivo-slider

After an Upgrade of the NexGen Gallery Plugin the nivo-slider that is being used by the theme stopped working and I get the following error:

"Error: TypeError: $(...).load is not a function"

I know this has something to do with the way jquery is being loaded but I have no idea on how to fix it. :( any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is the `$(window).load()` part a snippet you placed in or called in by the plugin? If you replace `$` with `jQuery`, thus `jQuery(window)..`

Comment: There is no (window).load() call anywhere in the template code... still looking for where I could apply this. :(

Comment: At last I found it...  however it seems just replacing $ with jQuery is not the solution. :( what am I missing?

original:
<script type='text/javascript'>$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
variable...});
});</script>

modified:
<script type='text/javascript'>jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider({
variable...});
});</script> (cant use linebreaks... :()

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like jQuery is being called twice, once by each plugin, resulting in a conflict where one takes precedence over the other. From what I remember, NivoSlider commonly conflicts with several other plugins that use jQuery because it calls its own jQuery, resulting in one plugin just "breaking". Here is NivoSlider's jQuery location on your server:

/wp-content/themes/twenty-plus-pro/inc/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js?ver=3.8

The only solutions I've seen for this type of error either involve use of the WordPress function [wp_deregister_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) (which I've never used so I don't want to advise you incorrectly on it), but the far more common "solution" seems to be disabling NivoSlider and remaking the slider using a different plugin.

I'm sorry I can't be of more help, but i hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: The theme I am using already makes use of the deregister function and it used to work until the update... checking this out pointed me in the right direction though :) thanks!